# SQL: New Column from value in Column C based off Column B for every value of Column A

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please see the table below.

> Product Name|--------Tag-------|--Sub-tag
>
> Product 1------|-Security Level-|--Full
>
> Product 1------|-------Color-------|--Orange
>
> Product 1------|----Region C----|--City A
>
> Product 2------|-Security Level-|--Limited
>
> Product 2------|----Region B----|--City F

In this example, I want a new column that would return "Full" for the three rows of Product 1 and "Limited" for the two rows of Product 2. This is for SQL Server. So far, I've got the below but not sure to bring Column A into it:

CASE WHEN Tag = 'Security Level' THEN Sub-Tag END AS SecurityLevel

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Not sure what you are getting at. Am I correct in assuming that you want the Security-Level for each unique Product-Name ?

Answer (score 3):

Using conditional aggregation with a window function `max()` [**`over()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx):

```
select *
  , SecurityLevel = max(case when Tag='Security Level' then SubTag end) 
      over (partition by ProductName)
from t
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/BZKM65131

returns:

```
+-------------+----------------+---------+---------------+
| ProductName |      Tag       | SubTag  | SecurityLevel |
+-------------+----------------+---------+---------------+
| Product 1   | Security Level | Full    | Full          |
| Product 1   | Color          | Orange  | Full          |
| Product 1   | Region C       | City A  | Full          |
| Product 2   | Security Level | Limited | Limited       |
| Product 2   | Region B       | City F  | Limited       |
+-------------+----------------+---------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select [Product Name],
       case when exists(select 1 from your_table as B where [Sub-tag] = 'Full' and B.[Product Name] = A.[Product Name]) then 'Full'
            when exists(select 1 from your_table as B where [Sub-tag] = 'Limited' and B.[Product Name] = A.[Product Name]) then 'Limited'
       end as [SecurityLevel]
From your_table as A
Group by [Product Name]
```